# How to determine a file in command line is a string and whether it exists or not

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell

I wanna get a file from command line and open it. If the filename is not a string, it will print('Wrong type') and if the file can't be accessed or doesn't exist it will give an error with content 'Cannot find filename'. I wonder how can I do this. Is this code below right?

```
import sys
filename=sys.argv[1]

if type(filename) is str:
    pass
else:
    raise Exception('wrong type')
try:
    open(filename,'r')
except FileNotFoundError:
    raise FileNotFoundError('Cannot find filename')
```

Comment: What particular problem do you have with it?

Comment: This really belongs over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: sys.argv values will always be strings. What, I think, you want here is to either match the parameter to a file format {name}.{estension} or to `try` opening the file and `except` the `FileNotFound` exception

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas Exactly. Is my code right?

Comment: logically, I believe that the `type(filename) is str` will always default to `true`, so you i would replace that part with `sys.argv.__len__() >= 2`. its also worth to check if `sys.argv[1].__len__() > 0`.  But overall, i believe that your code does what you want it to do.

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas OK, thank u bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with posting this on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) tho, but still can simplify it:

```
import sys
filename=sys.argv[1]

if not isinstance(filename,str):
    raise Exception('wrong type')
try:
    open(filename,'r')
except FileNotFoundError:
    raise FileNotFoundError('Cannot find filename')
```

Simplifying `if`/`else` into a `if`, and more efficient is `isinstance`, instead of `type(..) == ..`

Btw `sys.argv[1]` is always a string so no need for `if` statement:

```
import sys
filename=sys.argv[1]

try:
    open(filename,'r')
except FileNotFoundError:
    raise FileNotFoundError('Cannot find filename')
```

Btw, `os.path.exists`:

```
if not os.path.exists(filename):
    raise FileNotFoundError
```

Comment: @AnYan Happy that i helped,

Comment: This is pointless, there is no way for `sys.argv` to ever contain something which isn't a string.

Comment: @tripleee It's at the bottom of the post, but i still will edit

Comment: @AnYan No need for `if`, `sys.argv` values are always strings

Comment: @U9-Forward yeah obviously...and I know that. But this is a question from a quiz.